# Laravel 5.2: How do you model-bind form checkboxes?

Tags: checkbox, laravel-5, model-binding

So basically i want to edit a shoe model which has: Name, description, color and size. The size attribute has options (some checked others unchecked depending on what's set in DB) which allows for different sizes to be checked depending on availability etc. I also want to be able to edit (check and/or uncheck). I'm trying to do a form model binding but I don't seem to get it right.

Product model:

```
Class Product extends Model {
  public function sizes() {
    return  $this->hasMany('App\Size');
  }
}
```

Size Model:

```
Class Size extends Model {
  public function products() {
     return  $this->hasMany('App\Product');
  }
}
```

Products Controller: `edit` action

```
Public function edit($id){
  $product = Product::find($id);
  return view('product.edit', ['product'=>$product]);
}
```

Now, the sizes table has men's sizes from size 6 to size 12 (i.e. 6,7,8,9,10,11,12). And i want all those options to show but display as 'checked' only the ones associated with this particular model. So if this model (shoe) has size 9 and 12 associated with it... have 9 and 12 options display 'checked' accordingly and the rest remain unchecked.

Edit View:

```
{!! Form::model($product, ['route'=>['product.update', $product->id], 'class'=>'form']) !!}

{!! Form::text('name') !!}
{!! Form::text('description') !!}
{!! Form::text('color') !!}

{!! Form::checkbox('size') !!}

{!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

That's where i'm at. thanks

Comment: The third argument from `Form::checkbox()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @felipsmartins what 3rd argument, boolean true/false ? Don't understand

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: If i set it to true or false its going to be check or unchecked regardless.

Comment: That is all about basic logic here! Just define a "flag" such as `$is_editing` from controller and check or uncheck based on this flag. Well... most likely you have not explained well your problem/question.

Comment: @felipsmartins i think you have been vague in your answer, quite frankly. I'm sure i have been clear what the question is and if there was something that you needed clarification its best to be specific instead of making generalisations like "you have not explained well your problem/question".  Look at your first answer: `The third argument from Form::checkbox() is what you're looking for.` - That doesn't help does it? So again, what is it you are not understanding from my question?